# Can you program FPGAs in C-like languages?

Tags: fpga

At university I programmed a FPGA in a C-like language. However, I also know that one usually programs FPGAs in Verilog or VHDL. Is this a designer choice? If so, what are the performance drawbacks?

I would ideally like to program the FPGA in a C-like language, rather than VHDL.

I was thinking of getting an Xilinx Virtex-5 if it makes any difference?

Comment: What is the objection to VHDL - syntax or capability?

Comment: Maybe OpenCL is more adequate: https://www.altera.com/products/design-software/embedded-software-developers/opencl/overview.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer is "yes, certainly".

Here's an excellent survey of C compilers for FPGAs and FPGA-based systems.

[C-to-hardware compiler (HLL synthesis)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5603285/1098754)

Performance drawbacks and considerations are found in the system architecture and communication bandwidths rather than in using C vs. a hardware design language (HDL). The considerations in using C vs. an HDL lies in programming time and software maintenance issues, not so much in performance.

Answer (score 35):

FPGA's are not processors. C is a language designed for processors.

Yes, there are C to FPGA compilers.

Are they a good idea? I'd say No. The design you're going to end up with is (from what I've seen) normally a state machine that has one state per line of code in the C. The state machine then moves through the states performing the algorithm. Either that or some other kind of Turing machine is put in place to execute the code.

This is *not* how somebody skilled in FPGA design would generally approach a problem. It's a slow, and potentially gate hungry way doing things.

In the same way that English is a better language to write a novel than Fortran, VHDL and Verilog are better languages to describe logic circuits than C.

If you're serious about using FPGAs, use a language that is designed to describe logic circuits. It might be a steep learning curve, but the results will be much better IMHO.

Comment: Of course, it is also possible to translate C programs into VHDL or Verilog using a [C to HDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_to_HDL) compiler.

Answer (score 8):

You can install a soft processor core *inside* the FPGA logic, and run your C code inside the virtual processor. Xilinx has Microblaze (licensed) and Picoblaze (free) cores.  There are other soft cores you can implement as well (MIPS, x86, 8051, etc).

However, this is largely considered a "hack", as the cores are very slow compared to real cores.  And I think that *any* C-to-FPGA conversion is ultimately going to start smelling like running a soft core, and not give you the efficiency you deserve for running on a FPGA. FPGAs are not Turing machines, they are a sack of logic gates. You can build a Turing machine out of the gates, but that is not why you bought the sack of gates.

Its sort of like buying a bag of Legos, and building a hammer and set of nails out of the bricks. It might work, but you are better off buying a hammer to pound nails, and better off building Castles, Space Ships and Fire Stations with the Legos.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add something that I believe is the closest answer to the OP's question. If you're looking for a C-like language (which is not the same as C), you should definitely check out [Synflow](https://www.synflow.com). The idea is to have a modern language that allows you to design faster without the learning curve of VHDL/Verilog and with no overhead. Also it's free and open source!

Disclosure: I'm co-founder of Synflow :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at SystemC. The advantages of using a C based language is plentiful. Especially, on a system design perspective you can utilize that your other software (firmware and other low level stuff) is written in C. Hence, your software team can on a really early stage test against the rtl code.

In 2011, Xilinx bought the company AutoESL that had developed high level synthesis with SystemC. Xilinx has reused the name when the released its product "AutoESL". Especially with their new circuit Zynq, there a dual core ARM Cortex A9 embedded together with the FPGA logic, this will probably become a powerful tool for system development.

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed some compilers that allow you to infer (solve using an incomplete description) hardware circuits using a high-level language like C. "C-to-gates" is in fact a popular buzzword. The image companies advertise is that programmers are able to write hardware if the language they use is one they have used to describe software. This is incredibly wrong for a number of reasons, chief among them being the fundamental differences between the execution model assumed by languages like C and hardware description languages.

An illustrative example: C assumes at its heart a large randomly accessible linear-addressed memory - an assumption that rarely holds for hardware. A C-to-gates compiler faces a challenging task of interperting the **behavior** of the program described, and designing a hardware circuit with the same behavior.

While C-like languages are a great productivity tool in limited use cases, these compilers certainly don't allow you to suddenly know how to design hardware if you are familiar with C.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

I guess you used Handel C. Its a subset of C. From what I know the result is not very optimized. Verilog and VHDL allows for more optimization. I am saying this based on the my experience with Handel C a few years back

Comment: Does anyone support Handel C any more?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at C-to-hardware technology, where you can write C code and it will get compiled/translated to VHDL or Verilog. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603285/c-to-hardware-compiler-hll-synthesis) lists a few compilers. Haven't used it myself so I don't have any experience with it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Many designers write VHDL/Verilog instead of a high-level language, for the same reasons that many programmers used to (and still do in some cases) write assembly instead of Java: you can tune resource usage and performance at a low level. Both VHDL and Verilog are languages designed for designing hardware. C is not. Given enough time, you could always write a program in VHDL/Verilog that will outperform a high-level language program. What an HLL gives you is 1) faster development, 2) ease of maintenance, and 3) possibly greater portability.

There have been many efforts to compile existing high-level programming languages (C is one) to FPGA targets. Most of them do, in fact, generate optimized code. Impulse C, for example, is a subset of C with some add-on libraries that support process-level parallelism, plus a compiler that optimizes the C input for instruction-level parallelism, too. It pipelines loops, maps certain operations to high-performance hardware primitives it knows the underlying FPGA family provides, etc. (Full disclosure: I helped build the Impulse C toolchain.)

The [C-to-hardware environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603285/c-to-hardware-compiler-hll-synthesis) list Carlito and David Pointer link to is pretty exhaustive. Xilinx Virtex-5 is supported by many of them, and if you're using any recent FPGA family from a major vendor, choice of hardware shouldn't be a problem. Some of the HLL environments support built-in (or softcore) embedded CPUs better than others.