# Is conversion from OpenCV code to FPGA code is easier than Matlab code or not?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, fpga

I want to do project on image processing. i want to know if i want to implement this project on FPGA, which tool should I choose at 1st stage Matlab or OPEN CV?  and is it possible to convert code from Open CV to FPGA directly like code generator can be used from Matlab to FPGA directly??

Comment: Not sure, but that's unlikely.

Comment: It depends on which one you are more comfortable with. I would go for Matlab, since it is much more stable and mature and easier to debug.

Comment: Nowadays the best way of achieve it is using a Raspberry pi yeah! you have direct access to sensors or actuators.

Answer (score 16):

Firstly - why do you want to use an FPGA?  Unless you have good reasons to, avoid it!

Good reasons can be things like:

- cost
- power
- size
- pre-existing hardware which must be re-used
- personal interest
- it's an assignment where FPGAs are mandated

Bad reasons include "image-processing... that must mean I need an FPGA!"

---

## Think FPGA

If you want to implement on FPGA you need to think "FPGA" right from the beginning.  They have very particular characteristics compared to conventional processors, which means that many "conventional" algorithms are very difficult to implement efficiently on FPGAs.  And other algorithms which conventional processing will struggle with can actually be done quite simply on an FPGA.

One classic (non-image) example is CRC calculation, which is often implemented using lookup tables in software, but can be a trivial shift-register and XOR gate in FPGA.

### Regarding code generators....

There used to be a product which Xilinx bought (AccelDSP) which could take (very carefully crafted) Matlab code and produce VHDL.  It didn't do very well and was withdrawn.

Matlab have [HDL-coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/hdl-coder/), which purports to do the same job, as well as doing Simulink diagrams too.  I evaluated it quite a long time ago - I don't know how good it is now (although it was eye-wateringly expensive!).  Looking at the web page ti still only seems to support Matlab functions (not user defined objects) which makes it a non-starter for anything which stores state in it (IMHO) as all the state must be stored outside the function, meaning you have to have an "in" and "out" `struct` with all your regs in.  Same problem as AccelDSP had.

Xilinx System Generator and Altera's System Builder both use Simulink as a front-end to producing FPGA code.  They can be quite successful, be be aware that you can't just throw arbitrary complex Simulink blocks down and hope to produce a synthsisable FPGA.

Again, you have to think FPGA from the start.

### FPGA features

Wherever a comparative word is used, I am comparing to "conventional desktop processors"

- FPGA's are memory poor but they have lots of small blocks, which means their aggregate internal bandwidth can be enormous, if you have enough small jobs to do.  The memory is also very low latency (single clock-cycle), much like a processor's L1 cache
- Selections (`if..else` like functionality) can be quite expensive in terms of FPGA area
- multiplications are a limited resource, so it can sometimes pay to use algorithms from the "olden-days" when processors didn't have MUL instructions
- bit widths can be arbitrary - no need to use 32 bit elements to represent the 18 bit result of a calculation.  Much of the time, the tools can figure this out for you.

The development cycle is also different.

- Simulations are relatively quick to compile and run.  Ensure you do lots of this
- Actually synthesising and place-and-route (the operations which get you to a "bitstream" which you can program into the FPGA chip itself) can be very long-running.  My current compile (which is relatively small) just took 30 mins. You want to avoid doing this as much as possible!

Comment: The product [HDL coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/hdl-coder/) is still provided by Mathworks. Here is a recent blog post showing how to convert an image processing algorithm from MATLAB to FPGA using code generation: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/04/11/matlab-to-fpga-using-hdl-codertm/

Answer (score 11):

Xilinx has a tool called [Vivado HLS](http://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/vivado/integration/esl-design/index.htm).

There is also an appnote ([XAPP1167](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp1167.pdf)) that describes targetting OpenCV on Zynq platform using the tool.

I do not have experience with this but learnt about it at a recent OpenCV meet.  Here is the opening from the appnote -

> This application note describes how the OpenCV library can be used to develop computer
>   vision applications on Zynq devices. OpenCV can be used at many different points in the
>   design process, from algorithm prototyping to in-system execution. OpenCV code can also
>   migrate to synthesizable C++ code using video libraries that are delivered with Vivado HLS.
>   When integrated into a Zynq design, the synthesized blocks enable high resolution and frame
>   rate computer vision algorithms to be implemented.

[Altera supports OpenCL](http://www.altera.com/products/software/opencl/opencl-index.html#sdk) which is a broad specification to parallelize ANSI C.  There is a [OpenCV module](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/8140-OpenCL-module-for-OpenCV) available for OpenCL.  Again I do not have experience with this (yet ;)).

[This link](http://www.cmsoft.com.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=59&Itemid=106) helps to understand use of OpenCL in the context of host and hardware accelerators such as FPGA development boards.

So if you would like to go the Altera route, then you would have to wrap your OpenCV functions in OpenCL using the OpenCV module noted above and then use Altera's SDK to target the fpga.  The upside of going this route is that if you find that FPGAs are not so great for your application, then you could target the OpenCL+OpenCV to some other platform.

Comment: I forgot to mention, both Altera and Xilinx have tools that let you go from Matlab to HDL.  In case of Altera you could get these free with some development boards.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab provides a support to HDL. It provides packages where you can directly convert a matlab code to HDL code. You can also use it for programming FPGA's.

[HDL Coder](http://fr.mathworks.com/products/hdl-coder/)

On the other hand, it's not as easy to convert an Opencv to an HDL language because of the libraries. You can easily convert an Obect Oriented Programming(OOPs) language such as C++ to a Verilog / VHDL, but because of "OpenCV libraries", It will create some problems.