# What can I use for developing on FPGA (Virtex): C, C++, OpenCL, MPI?

Tags: c++, c, opencl, mpi, fpga

What can I use for developing on FPGA Virtex-5 or Virtex-7: C, C++, C++11, OpenCL, MPI?
And what is mostly usually uses for this?

There are:

- [SystemC is a set of C++ classes and macros which provide an event-driven simulation interface in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemC)
- [AutoESL](http://www.electronicsweekly.com/news/design/embedded-systems/xilinx-acquires-esl-firm-to-make-fpgas-easier-to-use-2011-01/)
- [Vivado HLS](http://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/vivado/integration/index.htm) - ([High-level synthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_synthesis))
- [VHDL (VHSIC(very-high-speed integrated circuits) Hardware Description Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL)
- [Software-based system realization with C/C++ and Future plans for OpenCL support](http://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/all-programmable-abstractions.html#software-based)

Comment: I think you have to go with System Verilog or something equivalent. "Compiling" to FPGA is not the same as compiling C++ (the architecture is different).

Comment: If you have the Verilog/VHDL to produce a processor in your FPGA, and there is a C or C++ compiler for that processor, I don't see why you can't use C or C++, and possibly also OpenCL or MPI, if the environment provides the resources to run that. But the FPGA itself is produced using a "hardware description language" of some sort.

Comment: @Synxis  However, I have met a lot of literature that describes how to use C, OpenCL and MPI for FPGA. Has anyone used the MPI for FPGA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A FPGA is just a big configurable circuit, and developing for it is creating a program that is "compiled" into a gigantic map of how the transistors and other low-level components are configured. It is fundamentally different from a normal CPU, or even a GPU : it is massively parallel at a very low level.

Programming such board requires another way of thinking. There are two main strategies:

- Develop with System Verilog, or another HDL (Hardware Description Language),
- Use SystemC, or other wrapper that allows you to use C/C++ for FPGA (it will be less optimized)

Normally, the board should come with a manual indicating what to use to program it.

On a personal side, I never used OpenCL with a FPGA (but I used CUDA for GPGPU), so I don't know how it works (but I think you have some overhead, as you have to emulate some small computing units).

Comment: Big thanks! There are many C-to-hardware compilers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603285/c-to-hardware-compiler-hll-synthesis  But, which of these compilers supports Verilog5/7 Xilinx? And does OpenCL support at Altera and Xilinx, as said here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603285/c-to-hardware-compiler-hll-synthesis

Comment: As far as I know there are already OpenCL systems on FPGA working much better than C. Altera did already support compiling OpenCL to cores, Xilinx announced it will be possible also.

Comment: I only programmed an Altera board with System Verilog, so I cannot really help you with C wrappers. However, please keep in mind than even with these wrappers, you have to think differently.